# Blazor WebAssembly, 'Could not find a part of the path '/sample-data/DBFile.json'.'

Tags: c#, json, path, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In **Blazor WebAssembly**.
The error `'Could not find a part of the path '/sample-data/DBFile.json'.'` appends but I don't know why.

---

Here is my code :

```
public void SaveData(List<Object> list)
{
    try
    {
        var output = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(list);
        var path = "sample-data/DBFile.json";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, output);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that read the file :

```
var response = await _http.GetAsync(jsonPath);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MotoDTO>>(content);
}
else
{
    return new List<MotoDTO>();
}
```

In blazor I don't really know how to write a file path...
Thanks for help

Comment: I hope i have answered your question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176497/how-to-overwrite-a-file-in-blazor-wasm/76180569#76180569

Comment: I think i'm going to do an SQL database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Blazor WebAssembly usually runs in the client web browser and has no access to the filesystem (at least not through the dotnet Filesystem apis).

You can use the browser's `Local Storage` API to store data locally.

A popular library is [Blazored.LocalStorage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.LocalStorage/)

Comment: But I can read files that are placed in the `wwwroot`. Why couldn't I write it ?

Comment: That seems inconsistent with expectations - can you show the code that reads files?

Comment: @Miser Magoo, I added the code that read the json file.

Comment: So you are reading the file using an http request - not through a filesystem - that is the difference and reason why reading works. Where (which computer) do you want to store the data you are trying to write? On the client (use LocalStorage) or on the host that is serving your  app (The server would need an api you can call)