# How to overwrite a file in blazor wasm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i want to edit a ics file and this is my code!

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var icsFile = await http.GetStringAsync("calendarEventList.ics");
        await ReadIcsFile(icsFile);
    }

    private async Task ReadIcsFile(string file)
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles, WriteIndented = true };
        var calendar = Calendar.Load(file);
        var iCalSerializer = new CalendarSerializer();
        foreach (var component in calendar.Children)
        {
            if (component is CalendarEvent e)
            {
                string sumer = Regex.Match(e.Summary, @".[^(]+$").ToString();
                if (sumer == "(HIGH)")
                {
                    e.Priority = 1;
                    Alarm ala = new Alarm
                        {
                            Summary = e.Summary,
                            Action = AlarmAction.Display,
                            Trigger = new Trigger(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-15)),
                        };
                    component.AddChild(ala);
                }
            }
        }
        string content = iCalSerializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
    }
```

so this way i read events from calendar file with iCal lib and add alert to some of them, but i dont know how can i rewrite the old ics file or even create new one...
how can i access wwwroot folder file in blazor wasm to create or update ics file?

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly executes in your client's browser. It doesn't (or, shouldn't) have write access to the wwwroot folder on your hosting provider. Where should this file exist, on the host for everyone to view, or per client?

Comment: @gunr2171 Thanks for the clear point that I was not aware of, based on what you said obviously because might be user upload that file so I need to manage that on server side.
How should I access from razor component to server project wwwroot?

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a Web API that the frontend (the WASM project) talks with. More to setup but better in all aspects in the long run.

Comment: You still haven't answered the first comment here. What is the desired 'flow' of those files?

Comment: @HH What difference does it make? The file is uploaded from the management panel and each user can change it for himself. But in any case, changes must be made in the file from the backend and the file must be saved in the database for each user.

Comment: You didn't tell us about a database before. Why do you still need a file? We don't know your project or goals, see [ask]

Comment: @HH because i don't wanted to handle this in database... after suggestion of gunr2171i choose to change the approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write files from a blazor wasm app to the file system without permission. However it seems to be possible to write files with the FileSystemApi.

A blazor based version can be found [here](https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess). I never used it so i can not comment on the steps involved.

But there are some alternatives not writing directly to the clients filesystem.

1. Use a server-side Blazor app: If you are using server-side Blazor
   you can write files to the server's file system, which is
   more secure than writing to the client-side file system.
2. Write to the BrowserStorage to store data. A detailed explaination can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ba16f6bb6934842d78c89ab5314f4b56)
3. You could call an api that handles the files on a backend server.
4. You could store the data in a database or cloud storage service.

Comment: yeah thanks man as @gunr2171 said third option is the best way to doing this.

Comment: I don't think it IS the best option.  If you need a server for your page to run, then I recommend using server-side Blazor.

Comment: Just to be clear about something, you _can_ write to the users filesystem. There are new APIs that only require user consent once.